# Recyclerview cannot get last child Android (getChildAt(pos)) Adapter items > RecyclerView children

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a several recyclerviews (added programatically), I am testing the first recyclerview for onKeyUp event.  thir rv has an adapter with 7 items, but the rv has only 6 children when I call rv.getChildCount().  but on screen I can see 7 items (only full 5 at a time), so whats wrong with recyclerview?

I just want to set a drawable background when the user press some keys for navigate in the recyclerviews.

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    int pos=Integer.parseInt(PosListon.get(ListonCur));
    int cant=Integer.parseInt(CantInListon.get(ListonCur));
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A) { //right
      if(pos<cant-1) {
          RecyclerView rv =(RecyclerView) llmain.getChildAt(ListonCur);
          rv.smoothScrollToPosition(pos+1);

          int caadp=rv.getAdapter().getItemsCount();//this shows 7
          int ca=  rv.getChildCount();//this shows 6

          RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout) rv.getChildAt(pos+1);//this is null whene index (pos+1) is 6
   rl.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_selected)); //if rl is null then here is an exception
          pos++;

                  PosListon.set(ListonCur, pos + "");//record pos in List

          return true;


      }}

    }
```

I know this may be associated whit the items currently presented on screen but I need help on how to haldle it.

Answer (score 0):

use `rv.getLayoutManager().getChildAt()` or `rv.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition`

Comment: I tried both, and I getting same result: null  when trying to get last child